# The crawler uses Selenium to dynamically switch IPs

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

When I use Selenium crawler to crawl website information, how do I set up dynamic switching proxies?
How to change the IP without closing the browser with selenium+chrome

```
# API URL
url = "https://api.docip.net/v1/get_openproxy?api_key=JB9jysZRRmPYwoq680rn4656c4345&num=1000&proxy_type=&country_type=&sort_type=2&ports=&unports=&areas=&unareas=&quchong=0&format=json"
response = requests.get(url)
proxies_list = []
if response.status_code == 200:
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    for item in data:
        proxy = {
            'http': 'http://' + item,
            'https': 'http://' + item
        }
        proxies_list.append(proxy)

else:
    print("Error: Unable to fetch data from API")

proxy_index = 0
```

How do I dynamically switch IP addresses by proxy_index an index?

I want to be able to dynamically switch IPs while the code is running, rather than shutting down the browser